# What is the difference between ice cream, gelato, and sorbet?

Tags: dessert, ice-cream, sorbet

What is the difference between ice cream, gelato, and sorbet? They look different, but are they made differently?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, the names vary a bit from country to country, or the ingredients do.
I'll explain the most common names/ingredients.

The main difference is in the ingredients used. Sorbet is basically water + sugar + fruit, while ice cream and gelato is milk/cream + sugar + fruit. So the last two are more 'creamy', while sorbet is more 'icy'.

You can say that ice cream is a type of gelato, but there still is a difference. More sugar in gelato, more butterfat (the percentage of fat in the milk/cream) in ice cream.

You can read quite a lot about ice cream on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream).

Comment: +1 for recognising that these words are not absolute, and vary from culture to culture. We do a fruit vodka sorbet with cream (basically a sorbet made from fruit infused vodka with cream stirred in at the end). If you are brave try it with chilli vodka !!!

Comment: I think you probably had the right idea, but your comparison of gelato and ice cream came out a little off. Gelato has more sugar and less butterfat than ice cream ([wikipedia notes some typical percentages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelato)). Also, I might describe sorbet as icy rather than watery.

Comment: Thanks for the 'icy', it was the word I was looking for :-)

Comment: @TFD: In some places, sorbet with a little cream mixed in is known as "sherbet" (although the words have almost identical etymology).

Comment: You might also note the difference between ice cream made with custard (cooked eggs, sugar, and cream) and ice cream made with only dairy.

Comment: Gelato also usually has less air whipped into it compared to regular ice cream, giving it a denser texture. See the [gelato page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelato) for more information on gelato

Answer (score -1):

1) Custard ice-cream with eggs milk and cream.(Quite a high portion of eggs)
2) Ice-cream (dairy) 10% upwards of milk fat (milk & cream)
3) Gelato less than 10% butter fat but upwards of 16% sugar (needed to balance recipe)
4) Sorbet fruit, water and some milk to give it body
5) Water ice fruit water and sugar

Comment: Sorbets are usually dairy free.

Comment: @sourd'oh of course... perhaps he was thinking sherbet.

Answer (score -2):

Gelato is kind of Italian icecream, which has more sugar & Fat content .